# I'm Using lwc component at case record page to perform action on record and once user clicks on submit, it should reload the record page

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, salesforce-id

The below code is working in standard app but not in salesforce console.I wrapped the LWC component into aura , but still it is not working

```
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import Updatecase from '@salesforce/apex/getCaseDetails.Updatecase'
import Action__c from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Action__c'
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { CurrentPageReference } from
  'lightning/navigation';
export default class caseApprovalStatus extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  @track openmodel = false;
  @track record;
  @track comments;
  @track value;
  Priority = '';
  @track PickListValue;
  @api recordId;
  @api show = false;
  @track action;

  @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;


  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA', fieldApiName: Action__c })
  PicklistValues({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      console.log(data.values)
      this.PickListValue = data.values;
      this.errors = undefined;
    }
    if (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  }

  openmodal() {
    this.openmodel = true
  }
  closeModal() {
    this.openmodel = false
  }
  saveMethod() {
    this.closeModal();
  }

  onchangecase(event) {
    if (event.target.label === 'Approval comments') {
      this.comments = event.target.value;
    }
    this.action = this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').value;
  }
  clearfields(event) {
    if (event.target.label === 'Approval comments') {
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }
  navigateToViewRecordPage() {
    console.log('in navigation by')
    console.log(this.recordId)
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__recordPage',
      attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        objectApiName: "Case",
        actionName: "view"


      },
    });
  }




  errorCallback(error, stack) {
    this.error = error;
  }
  addCaseFeed(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Updatecase({ casePr: this.comments, caseid: this.recordId, action: this.action })
      .then(() => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Record Is Updated',
            variant: 'sucess',

          }),
        );
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.navigateToViewRecordPage()

      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error on data save',
            message: 'Inputs not valid',
            variant: 'error',
          }),
        );
      });


  }

}

    <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
      <c:caseApprovalStatus recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
    </aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';` and change your LWC name to extend Navigatio Mixin:

```
export default class YourClassName extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) { 
   // Your code here
}
```

Comment: import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';                                                              
export default class caseApprovalStatus extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {My code}, I am already doing it

Comment: Yes, I think we need to see all  the code to be more helpful here..

Comment: I edited the code above